# Why does this sierpinski triangle draw randomly and not following the code?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I needed to do one for my school assignment but this code draw randomly. I copied some Stack Overflow code but I don't understand the logic. Can someone explain it to me?

```
import turtle
def triangle(width,height):

    if height==0:

        for i in range(3):
            t.fd(width)
            t.left(120)
    else:

        triangle(width/2,height-1)
        t.fd(width/2)
        triangle(width/2,height-1)
        t.bk(width/2)
        t.left(60)
        t.fd(width/2)
        t.right(60)
        triangle(width/2,height-1)
        t.left(60)
        t.bk(width/2)
        t.right(60)


window = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
triangle(100,2)
window.exitonclick()
```

What does the first if statement do? Does the first if statement draw the last triangle or what? Where does it draw the triangle because it never drawed a triangle that size on the script. The only triangle that is the same size as 100x100x100 in width is the triangle outside which is made out a lot of small triangles.

The (height-1) 3 times in the function, that would make height negative 1? At height 0 it would draw a big triangle and there's no big triangle on the window that start from the width then go up and then back down. Also in the else statement the width is 25 because the triangle the statement above divided 100 by 2 and then after that divided the width(50) by 2 again?

Comment: Your title says something else than (all of) your questions. What is your level of understanding in Python? That first if checks if the height equals 0, for example – is there something ambiguous about it?

Comment: Well, it doesn't draw the triangle the same size as 100x100x100 anywhere. I'm beginner experience but I don't understand how it draws

Comment: Maybe you should play around with the turtle commands a bit to understand what they do (and read the documentation, of course). And some knowledge about the concept of recursion would be helpful, too.

Comment: The naming `height` is really misleading. It is actually the deepness of recursion levels in the sierpinski triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the way your code is naming the variable is very misleading.
Because when this code uses the variable `height`, it actually doesn't refer to the 'height of the triangle'. Instead, this height is an indicator of when to stop the recursion.

FYI, recursion is a procedure of function calling itself, like f(f(f(f()))).
On the example I gave just now, it is a recursion of 4 iteration, as the function f calls itself 4 times.

If the variable `height` passed to the `triangle()` was 0, the first if statement knows that it doesn't have to do any recursion, so it simply draws a single triangle of side 100.

```
if height==0:

        for i in range(3):
            t.fd(width)
            t.left(120)
```

[image]

Now if the `height` variable was 1, it calls three new `triangle` function with each `height` variable 0, and each side 50.

```
else:

        triangle(width/2,height-1) #notice how height is reduced by one
        t.fd(width/2)
        triangle(width/2,height-1)
        t.bk(width/2)
        t.left(60)
        t.fd(width/2)
        t.right(60)
        triangle(width/2,height-1)
        t.left(60)
        t.bk(width/2)
        t.right(60)
```

so it draws 3 smaller triangles.

[image]

With `height` variable 2, imagine that each of the three triangles also calls another 3 triangles (so there will be total of 9 triangles of each side 25).

Hope this made the everything a little clearer :)

Comment: If the width,height is 100,1. First it would call a the function triangle again and change the width and height to 50, 0 and then the t.fd 50/2= 25 and then since height is 0 it will go to the if statement?

Comment: oh, I get it now, so the triangle call the function and the if statement became width/2 automatically but the line below it doesn't change the width. I had to play around with it for along time jeez self taught programmers must have a lot of dedication.